# Problem when doing spatial panel regression with R: Not yet able to subset general weights lists

Tags: r, panel, geospatial, spatial

I met a problem when doing spatial panel regression (SAR) with R with package splm and spdep. When I was trying to do a regression with `spml()`, it occurred an error said that

> Error in subset.listw(listw, subset, zero.policy = zero.policy) : Not yet able to subset general weights lists

I learnt from google that it maybe because there contains NAs in my spatial weighted matrix, but i found that none of values in the matrix was NAs, and then i tried to replace all 0 with 0.00001 but it also failed. I really hope to get some advice from you.

Comment: Please post a minimum working example with the data and code